UsePythonVersion0 error in self hosted runner on windows
Following is the code in my yml file.
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'


I am using DevOps on self-hosted runner installed on windows 10. Getting following error.
There is python-3.12.5-amd64.exe in C:\agent_work_tool\Python\3.12.5\x64 directory.

##[error]Failed to download Python from the Github Actions python registry (https://github.com/actions/python-versions). Error: Error: The process 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Version spec 3.12 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
Versions in C:\agent_work_tool:
This is error i am getting

The cause of the issue can be that you haven't configured the python directory correctly. You can refer to the steps in my answer to configure the Python directory again and check if it can work.

Refer to this doc: UsePythonVersion@0 - Use Python version v0 task
To setup the Python files in self-hosted agent, you need to follow the directory structure in _tool folder:
$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/
    Python/
        {version number}/
            {platform}/
                {tool files}
            {platform}.complete

If the python folder only contains .exe file, the configuration is not valid.
You can refer to the following steps to configure the Python files to use  UsePythonVersion@0 Task.
Step1: Download the required Python version package in Github: Python-versions
In your case, you have downloaded the correct package(contain python-3.12.5-amd64.exe).
Step2: We need to manually execute the python-3.12.5-amd64.exe. It will generate all configuration files.
Path: C:\Python312 or C:\Users\(Your logged in User)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312
For example:

Step3: We need copy all files in Python312 folder and paste them to the path C:\agent\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.5\x64

Step4: We need to create an empty file: x64.complete at the same path of x64 folder.
For example:

Here is the full directory structure:
$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/
    Python/
        3.12.5/
            x64/
                {tool files}
            x64.complete

Finally, you can use the Use Python version task in Azure Pipeline to set the correct version.
YAML sample:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.12.5'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'

Result:

